# How can I add a submenu option for the main menu options using dialog in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, dialog

I am currently working on a bash script using menu based context and functions. everything works flawless. But I am wanting to change and edit some options around while adding sub menu to each option.

```
#!/bin/bash

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="Backtitle here"
TITLE="Title here"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"

OPTIONS=(1 "Option 1"
         2 "Option 2"
         3 "Option 3")

CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                --title "$TITLE" \
                --menu "$MENU" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
        1)
            echo "You chose Option 1"
            ;;
        2)
            echo "You chose Option 2"
            ;;
        3)
            echo "You chose Option 3"
            ;;
esac
```

How do I go about adding the submenu to this dialog box?

For example, I need the first main menu as categories. The subcategories in each main category, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Just run another dialog inside the `case` statement. Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

choice=$(dialog \
   --input-fd  2 \
   --output-fd 1 \
   --menu main 10 40 5 1 A 2 B \
)

case "$choice" in
   1)
      choiceA=$(dialog --input-fd 2 --output-fd 1 --menu sub-A 10 30 5 1 A1 2 A2)
      ;;
   2)
      choiceB=$(dialog --input-fd 2 --output-fd 1 --menu sub-B 10 30 5 1 B1 2 B2)
      ;;
esac

stty sane
clear
```

If you want the user to be able to go back to the first menu then you need to implement this in the script (possibly with `--default-item`).

The downside is each `dialog` rewrites the screen on its own. I haven't found any option to keep the old content (leftover from the previous `dialog`) and only to draw over it. Therefore you cannot create cascading menus this way.

There is `--and-widget`, in general you can do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

choice=$(dialog \
   --input-fd  2 \
   --output-fd 1 \
   --begin 2 2 \
   --menu first 10 40 5 1 A 2 B \
   --and-widget --begin 4 4 \
   --menu second 10 40 5 11 X 22 Y \
)

stty sane
clear

echo "$choice"
```

But then the second menu is defined at the moment you call `dialog`, it cannot depend on what the user chooses in the first menu.

It seems one cannot do better with the `dialog` executable (i.e. `dialog(1)`). Probably one can do better with the dialog library (`dialog(3)`, see `man 3 dialog`). I'm not a programmer and I cannot help with this.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Especially with a related answer. Before I go an try this suggestion, I would like to understand what you meant by: _But then the second menu is defined at the moment you call dialog, it cannot depend on what the user chooses in the first menu._

Comment: @CybernetiXS3C I mean `--menu second 10 40 5 11 X 22 Y` is fixed. Even if you make it depend on some variables, it will get fixed at the moment the shell runs `dialog`. The variables can depend on anything that happens before `dialog`, but when the user sees the first menu, the second one is totally determined. So with a single `dialog` it's impossible to make the second menu depend on the user's choice in the first menu.

Comment: So there is no way to create something like this:    [Captain-Brute](https://github.com/cybernetix-s3c/Captain-Brute/)       into dialog menu form?

Comment: @CybernetiXS3C There is: like in my first example. But when people say "submenu", maybe they think about a situation where the main menu stays visible, at least partially. Compare [`iptraf`](http://www.taedium.com/rrd-iptraf/iptraf01.jpg). I wasn't sure how you want your menus and submenus to look like, so I didn't stop after the first example.

Comment: The setup I am trying to do is similar to my Captain-Brute. You run the script and get the first main menu. Each option within the first menu has another set of subcategories.  While each subcategory either has a function to a tool or another subcategory.

Comment: **Of course I DO NOT wish to recreate this particular tool**.  I just want to work with dialog.
Your first example is definitely in my direction.

Comment: @CybernetiXS3C Yes, my first example shows this is possible with separate `dialog` invocations. Then I state there's a downside: a new menu wipes the previous one from the terminal completely. If it's OK with you then go for it. The rest depends on the logic you implement in the script.

Comment: I am OK with new clean menu for each option for menus. I am now trying to find where to add a script command under the subcategories, as well as trying to also implement another subcategory under a subcategory from menu 2. My original script has the initial menu with tool names and direct functions along with call back to the main menu once the function is done running. I also have a quit button on the main.

Comment: I am thinking this would be easier if I create individual dialog script menus, and connect them all as "plugins".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108421/discussion-between-cybernetix-s3c-and-kamil-maciorowski).